# Is it ok to use companion object to save bundle for fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with loaded via network data, after that user can go to another fragment, and after return he won't see same data in the fragment.
Data is currently passed using arguments bundle.

Without storing in companion object, I will need to always keep bundle with every opened fragment to pass it when I need to return.

So, maybe, I need to store bundle in `companion object` to use it in `onCreateView` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can store bundle in companion object when calling instance of fragment for using:

```
 companion object {
    fun newInstance(id: Int, name: String) = TopFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putInt(Constants.ID, id)
                putString(Constants.NAME, name)
            }
        }
}
```